# I m getting Unauthenticated. on laravel sanctum api

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, axios

so I created the login it worked well but when I want to fetch user posts it returns Unauthenticated even tho I sent the token and used the xsrf cookies but still the same problem

axios call

```
     axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
 axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
  axios.get('/api/posts/20',{headers:{Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('userToken')}`}}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
  })
```

api route

```
Route::post('login',"UserController@index");
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostController@index')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

please help me guys keep in mind I tried everything out there but nothing works

Comment: probably you have stateful domain issue, can you please share back and front domain then your stateful domain? (stateful domain are been saved or in env with SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS or in sanctum config file.

Comment: 'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1')), || front http://localhost:3000/

Comment: maybe its the back domain issue that be 127.0.0.1 which is not as same origin of front, so be sure your front(i think its nuxtjs) on same domain or subdomain of backend domain.

Comment: I m using react

Comment: no different ...

Answer (score 0):

I had problem in domain as TEFO said I launched the backend on virtual host  + adding configuration to cors.php solved the problem